# Unity 3d  и другие движки.

Tags: iphone, 3d

Доброго времени суток. Кто нибудь пробовал разрабатывать на каких либо подобных движках? Что это и с чем это едят..? Реально ли сделать хорошее качественное приложение для мобильных устройств на них или это что то подобное cms  в webe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересный словооборот: "*Реально ли сделать хорошее качественное приложение для мобильных устройств на них или это что то подобное cms в webe*".

Начнем с того что на любом (хорошем) продукте будь то ЦМС в ВЕБ или игровой движек, мы можем сделать хорошее и качественное приложение. Вы говорите так будто хорошее и качественное приложение - это приложение с крутой графикой и 3D эффектами, а на самом деле это прежде всего идея (хороший пример - Angry Birds, там даже 3D нет).

Насчет Unity 3D могу сказать много положительного (из опыта программирования на десктоп), но для мобильных устройств я её не тестил.

В любом случае, мне кажется, что подобные системы идеальны для начинающих разработчиков, ибо даже если пробовать создавать движок самому - далеко не факт, что он будет быстрее (для создания быстрого движка нужны более высокие навыки). А у разработчиков более опытных таких вопросов возникать уже не будет, ибо эти люди оценивают свои потребности и возможности, и исходя из них делают выводы о средствах реализации.